# Get type parameter value from URL with livewire

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-livewire, livewires

I wanted to get the value of type from the url "example.com/user?type=agent" using livewire.

I have tried using Input::get('type') but is not working in livewire component class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
This is the example you can try:
```

```
        public $type;
        protected $queryString = ['type'];
        
        return view('bladefile',[
                    'posts' => Post::where('title', 'like', '%'.$this->type.'%')->get(),
                ]);
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it working using the documentation [Query String](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/query-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

[HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$type = $request->input('type');
```

[Helper Request Method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request)

```
$type = request('type');
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know livewire, but it's looks like laravel.
Just try

```
Input::query('type')
```